# quota restrictions

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I increase the quota restrictions imposed for querying and importing data to big query?

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy

Is there any form that I need to submit for this purpose? Is it possible to do it offline?

```
Queries
    Daily limit: 1,000 queries

Import Requests
    Daily limit: 1,000 import requests per day (including failures)
```

The query limit of 1000 is not sufficient for most of my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explained on the [Pricing page](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/pricing):

> If your needs exceed the default limits below, we encourage you
>   [contact a sales representative](http://www.google.com/enterprise/cloud/contact.html).

Comment: My company has already contacted about 13 days ago and there is no response. How do I follow-up?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery query quotas are going up today. They should be reflected in https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/quota-policy soon, but they are already live. The daily limit is now 20k queries per day, and some concurrent query quotas have been relaxed.